# Cannot destructure property 'crown_role_id' of 'client.db.settings.selectCrown.get(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript

I make a crown system for discord but i have this error...

> Cannot destructure property 'crown_role_id' of 'client.db.settings.selectCrown.get(...)' as it is undefined.

in this code:

```js
const { crown_role_id: crownRoleId, crown_schedule: cron } = client.db.settings.selectCrown.get(guild.id);
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Looks like the `get` function is returning undefined.

Comment: In case you can't guaranty that `client.db.settings.selectCrown` contains an item with key `guild.id`, you can fallback to an empty object: `client.db.settings.selectCrown.get(guild.id) || {}` this will eliminate the error, however `crown_role_id` and `crown_schedule` will be `undefined`, you'll need do additional checks